# Remote powershell doesn't return nested properties

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I need to get information about public folders from remote exchange servers and I use powershell for it. But there is a problem: remote powershell converts properties of result objects to strings:

```
$mailFolders = Invoke-Command -ConnectionUri:$uri –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Credential:$creds -ScriptBlock {
    Get-MailPublicFolder "\imdev-ie-025-pf1\sublevel1\sublevel2";
};

$mailFolders | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses
```

And this code returns:

```
smtp:sublevel2@imdev-ie-025-2.com
smtp:sublevel2@imdev-ie-025.com
```

But, if I execute cmdlet localy on exchange server then I recieve something like this

```
Get-MailPublicFolder "\imdev-ie-025-pf1\sublevel1\sublevel2" | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses

SmtpAddress        : sublevel2@imdev-ie-025-2.com
AddressString      : sublevel2@imdev-ie-025-2.com
ProxyAddressString : smtp:sublevel2@imdev-ie-025-2.com
Prefix             : SMTP
IsPrimaryAddress   : False
PrefixString       : smtp

SmtpAddress        : sublevel2@imdev-ie-025.com
AddressString      : sublevel2@imdev-ie-025.com
ProxyAddressString : smtp:sublevel2@imdev-ie-025.com
Prefix             : SMTP
IsPrimaryAddress   : False
PrefixString       : smtp
```

Do you have any idea how to get full tree of objects? 
Thanks.

Comment: What does `$mailFolder.GetType()` return?

Comment: This seems strange and probably something to do with how the results returned from remote commands are deserialized. A simple solution/workaround would be to just do the `| select` part on the remote server.

Comment: @MarkWragg, unfortunately the exchange session is constrained and the `Select` command isn't available

Comment: @MartinBrandl just PSObject